# Tracking downloads with google analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I've been trying to set up code to track downloads of files on a website. I just updated the code from the original tracking snippet to the asynchronous code, ga.js, (in the local.php5 file to track all pages on the site) but I don't know what code to use to track downloads on one certain page.

I found this code but I don't know if it is correct; it hasn't been showing any events when I check GA.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dl-tracking').on('click', function (){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download']);
    });
  });

</script>
```

the certain links are outputted using a for-each loop in PHP so I tried putting this code in to work

```
 $variable .= "<a href='$name/media/Material/$x->path' target='_blank  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'TM', 'Download',]);">$fileName</a>";
```

but I got a T_STRING error for that line. I'm a bit new to PHP so I don't know where my errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tracking Events in Analytics (whether *ga.js* or the newer *analytics.js*), the **Event Category** and **Event Action** are required (see the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking)):

> **category (required):** The name you supply for the group of objects you want to track.
>
> **action (required):** A string that is uniquely paired with each category, and commonly used to define the type of user interaction for
>   the web object.
>
> **label (optional):** An optional string to provide additional dimensions to the event data.
>
> **value (optional):** An integer that you can use to provide numerical data about the user event.
>
> **non-interaction (optional):** A boolean that when set to true, indicates that the event hit will not be used in bounce-rate
>   calculation.

You should thus have something similar to:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('.dl-tracking').on('click', function () {
      // You might want to also add the link text/href here:
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Click']);
   });
});
```

---

As for your PHP exception, it happens because your quote and double-quote characters (*'* and *"*) should be escaped in the following line of code:

```php
$variable .= "<a href='$name/media/Material/$x->path' target='_blank  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'TM', 'Download',]);">$fileName</a>";
```

It should be corrected to something similar to:

```php
$variable .= '<a href="'.$name.'/media/Material/'.($x->path).'" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'TM\', \'Download\']);">'.$fileName.'</a>';
```

Comment: You just have to replace the `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` snippet from your original post.

Comment: I have yet to implement that code; everything before the $(document).read(funciton()...)  I have on a file that tracks pageviews for all pages on the site. Because the downloadable links are only on one page, would I also put the jQuery code there as well; or should it just go on the page containing the links

Comment: Either will work. The Custom Event will only fire when users click on a `<a>` Element with the CSS class `dl-tracking`. If you have links with this CSS class elsewhere on your site (and you don't want those to be tracked), then having that jQuery snippet only on a specific page could be more straighforward. Else, having it on every single page would be fine too -- since it would only react to the proper link clicks. Bottom line is just to make sure jQuery has already been loaded.

Comment: and I still have to put that snippit of jQuery code between <script></script> tags correct?